# Currency format conversion

Tags: excel, vba, format, currency

My problem: Converting an Excel range from a currency format (USD) to another (EUR) and vice versa.

USD format in Excel looks like 123,456.00
EUR format in Excel looks like 123 456,00

where in USD values comma is the thousand separator and `.` is the decimal point
and
in EUR values space is the thousands separator and comma `,` is the decimal point.

I've tried some coding in VBA but I'm a newbie in this area.

Any help to build a VBA macro code for using in Excel spreadsheets?

Comment: My fault, VBA tag instead.
Sorry for that
Dark Side

Comment: Are those numeric values? The values are always the same - `123456` no matter what you do. It's the cell formatting that makes them appear differently.

Answer (score 0):

This UDF will do the job. Copy and paste into a module:

```
Function ConvertUSDToEUR(Amount As Range) As String
Dim TempStr As String: TempStr = Amount.Value
TempStr = Replace(TempStr, ",", " ")
TempStr = Replace(TempStr, ".", ",")
ConvertUSDToEUR = TempStr
End Function
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @DarkSide it works perfectly just copy and paste the function in a module

Answer (score 0):

With a value in **A1**, In **B1** enter:

```
=TEXT(A1,"#,##0.00")
```

and in **C1** enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B1,","," "),".",",")
```

For example:

[image]

**NOTE:**

It is also possible to transform the values "in place", but this would require *VBA.*

**EDIT#1:**

Here are two macros that will change formatting "in place".  Thus the results will still be numbers, but the appearance will change. Say we have a list of **numbers** *(not formulas)*:

[image]

Select the values and run this macro:

```
Sub MakeUS()
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Selection
        r.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    Next r
End Sub
```

to produce:

[image]

and this macro:

```
Sub MakeEUR()
    Dim r As Range, v1 As String, v2 As String, DQ As String
    DQ = Chr(34)
    For Each r In Selection
        v1 = Format(r.Value, "#,##0.00")
        v2 = Replace(Replace(v1, ",", " "), ".", ",")
        r.NumberFormat = DQ & v2 & DQ & ";;;"
    Next r
End Sub
```

to produce:

[image]

If the column contained **formulas**, the approach would be slightly different.

Comment: Hi Gary.
It works fine if my windows system is configured with English(USA).
But as my windows system is configured with Euro it doesn't work.
By the way, what are the challenges with formulas?
Thank you for helping me.
Dark Side

Comment: @DarkSide  Since my computer is configured *USA* I don't know how to help you.  The formula restriction is that the format is truly **static** for *EUR* It must be refreshed if the value changes.